# Proving exponential is greater than nlogn

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I prove the following:

$$n^a(logn)^a \leq a^n$$ for $ a > 1$ ?

A bit stuck on with the usual approach of

$$lim_{n\rightarrow\inf}\frac{a^n}{n^a(logn)^a}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$n^a(\log n)^a < n^a n^a = n^{2a}$$
so that
$$\frac{a^n}{n^a(\log n)^a} > \frac{a^n}{n^{2a}}$$
and since $a>1$ the expression on the right hand side tends to $\infty$, and therefore the expression on the left hand side tends to $\infty$ as well.

ADDED: if $a>1$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ then
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{n^b} = \infty$, since taking the logarithm we get that
$$\log\left(\frac{a^n}{n^b}\right)=\log(a^n)-\log(n^b)=n\log a - b\log n = n\log a\left(1 - \frac{b\log n}{n\log a}\right)$$
Notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b\log n}{n\log a}=0$ (for instance by L'Hopital's rule) and so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{a^n}{n^b}\right)=\infty$ and therefore the same is true for the original expression as well.

Comment: Thanks - are you able to prove that $a^n$ grows faster than $n^b$ for $a,b>1$?

Comment: @ilikemath3.14 I assumed that was known since you said 'the usual approach'. Would you like me to add a proof of that as well?

Comment: that would be helpful -> or if you could reference a proof

Comment: @ilikemath3.14 I added an explanation.